# A Compiled .exe can't find input file

Tags: c, visual-studio, compilation, sas

I have a compiled c code into .exe and can successfully execute the .exe in different locations by double clicking on it.

I am trying to use SAS to execute the .exe. There is error msg saying that the input file can't be found so .exe wasn't able to be executed appropriately.

I used Visual Studio to compile the c code. I am guessing it has something to do with how the code was compiled (such as the default directory where all the source and header files, and the input the file were saved at)?

Anyone can give me some ideas as for debugging and fixing the issue?

The SAS code used to call the .exe is pasted below and so is the error msg.

```
    x '"C:\Users\Gfish\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\M\Debug\M.exe"';
```

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqCBq.png)
Many thanks!!

Gfish

The error msg in SAS after calling the .exe again using infile and pipe is attached as well (i.e., error2)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPbRz.png)

Comment: Please post the SAS code used and the error received. As posted, this question does not meet SO rules.

Comment: Please read each tag's requirements and relevance by hovering on them, and please do not post text as image.

Comment: ... and the error message does not say "the input file can't be found", but "No file open".

Comment: What happens if you run that exact code via command line. Also, try %sysexec instead of X. When you have a path with spaces I find that method easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

For debugging OS commands in SAS I always prefer to use `infile` with `pipe` - this way you can extract any error / debug messages and use them for conditional logic.

Try:

```
data _null_;
 infile '"C:\Users\Gfish\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\M\Debug\M.exe" 2>&1' pipe;
 input;
 list;
run;
```

Note the `2>&1` - this redirects STDERR to STDOUT (so you get both in the stream).

Also - as @Reeza mentions - try running this first on a regular command line.  If it doesn't work there, it won't work in SAS.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I tried to call .exe in cmd and it worked but got the error in SAS using the above pipe and infile (See the original post).